# Single Sign On for Wordpress and OpenCart

Tags: wordpress, authentication, single-sign-on, opencart

I'm Looking for a SSO for integrating a Wordpress/Opencart website together.
I'm not looking for OpenCart as a primary login and neither the Wordpress as primary login. But a common 3rd party authentication method that both Wordpress and OpenCart can use.

While researching a little I've found [this](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=9133) plugin. But this one uses OpenCart as a primary authentication method.

I'm looking for something like [Mobile Nations](http://mobilenations.com) is using for their common authentication.

Comment: to the downvoters, I think questions about WP plugins, like questions about java libraries, are on topic here

Comment: Any idea or suggestion over the same?
I'm planning to create a new 3rd party application that'll signup/login users to both websites.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you need to look into **Social login** (aka Social sign-in).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_login
This allows users to use their existing social media login (Google, Yahoo, Facebook, Twitter, Paypal, etc.) or even [OpenID](http://openid.net/get-an-openid/what-is-openid/) to log into your sites.

The authorization process is simple, so when they go from one website to the next, it only takes a moment for them to authorize what personal information you can access and then they're in.  There's plenty of plugins/extensions for both platforms, so integrating this will be simple.

If you wanted to further "link" the accounts together, then simply store their user ID or other identifier *(email perhaps?)* from the social media login and then the two accounts can easily be matched.

You might also have a look at https://www.oneall.com, but the drawback there is it's a monthly fee and the Opencart extension must be purchased separately.

I'm not sure I completely grasped what you're looking for, but I hope that helps.